# Solve $x^2\equiv a$ mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $x_0$ solves  $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p$, where $p$ is a prime. Then $x_0$ solves  $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p^i$ for $i\geq1$. My question is: Is there a general way to find **all** the solutions to $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p^i$ given the solutions of $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p$?

Comment: I asked a somwhat related question, just concerned with $a=-1$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102353/modular-roots-of-1-for-successive-prime-powers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you stated the result backwards:

If $x_0$ solves $x^2=a \pmod{p^i}$ then $x_0$ solves $x^2 = a \pmod{p}$.

To go backwards, which is what you want, you have to use the [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma) . Hensell's lemma tells you that when you know a solution of $x^2=a \pmod{p}$, when a solution to $x^2=a \pmod{p^i}$ exists and how to get ALL the solutions which correspond to $x^2=a \pmod{p}$ (it actually workds for any polynomial).

For the equation you have, the Hensel Lemma tells you that when $p \neq 2$ and $a \neq 0$, there exists exactly one solution corresponding to $x_0$ for each $p^i$, and that things are a bit trickier when $p=2$ and/or $a=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ty, fixed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ups, fixed only the other 2 :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your comment is wrong , for example $7^2 = 15 \mod 17$ but $7^2 \not= 15 \mod 17^2 $ or $17^3$ and so on.

Secondly yes you can find all the solutions to $x^2 = a \mod p^i$ using Tonelli–Shanks algorithm with extra change to the algorithm that is instead of taking $p-1 = Q 2^s$ you will find $Q ,s$ such that $p^{i-1} (p-1) = Q 2^s$ because $\phi(p) = p-1$ and $\phi(p^i)= p^{i-1} (p-1)$.

note : i am not sure but i think with other modifications to the algorithm you can even solve $x^j = a \mod p^i$ (again i am not sure).

also this algorithm work for prime and prime power because they have explicit Euler phi formula but it will not work with composite numbers.